# How to test callbacks provided to subcomponents in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

I'm having trouble testing callbacks that a component provides to its children.

In the past, what I did was this:

```
const component = ReactDOM.render(<Subject />, node);
const collaborator = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(component, Collaborator);
collaborator.props.onSubmit(); // now I have a handle on the collaborator so I can call the callbacks it was given to my heart's content and assert what they do
```

But the issue is that `findRenderedComponentWithType` *does not work with function components*.

i.e. if Collaborator is implemented like this:

```
class Collaborator extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { onSubmit } = this.props;
    return <MyForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />;
  }
}
```

`findRenderedComponentWithType` will return a handle of the component, but if it is implemented like this:

```
function Collaborator({ onSubmit }) {
  return <MyForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />;
}
```

`findRenderedComponentWithType` won't find it!

Does anyone test like this?  I thought this was how I can allow `<Collaborator />` to evolve without needing to change the tests for `<Subject />` :(

Here is a codesandbox that demonstrates:

https://codesandbox.io/s/qzy39n46wq

What with function components being the new hotness w/ hooks, this is a big problem for my testing approach.

Comment: there is still no way doing that: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5555 so `findRenderedComponentWithType` does not intentioned to work with functional components :(